# DateSelect : columnwise selection applied to a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, dataset, date-and-time

Let consider :

- A time interval (January given by `Time`)
- A random set of values (Minimal example values given by `Val`)

as

```
Time = Map[DateObject, DateRange[{2022, 1, 1}, {2022, 1, 31}]];
Val = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length@Time];
```

If I would like to extract some data between two days of January, this can be done by using

```
DateSelect[Time, 20 > #Day > 1 &]
(*{{2022, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 15,0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 16, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022,1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, {2022, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.}}*)
```

Now let consider the following new dataset given by

```
Data = Transpose@{Time, Val};
```

I would like to extract some data with the function `DateSelect` but based on the first column of `Data`. For now I've tried :

- `DateSelect[Data, 20 > #Day > 1 &]` Failed
- `DateSelect[Data, 20 > #[[1]] > 1 &]` Failed
- `DateSelect[Data, 20 > #Day[[1]] > 1 &]` Failed

A possibility would be (but less elegant in my opinion)

```
Select[Data, 20 > DateValue[#[[1]], "Day"] > 1 &]
```

Any idea to restrict to `DateSelect`

Comment: `DateSelect` takes only a list of date objects (`DateObject`, `DateInterval`,`DateList`, `DateString`) as the first argument.So you cannot use `DateSelect[Data, pred]` for any `pred` to get the filtering you want. Perhaps you might find something like `Select[Data, 20 > #[[1]]["Day"] > 1 &]` less inelegant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message from execution of `DateSelect[Data, True &]` indicates

[image]

you can only use ***"a list of recognized date specifications or a date interval"***  (`DateObject`, `DateInterval`, `DateList`, `DateString`) as the first argument in `DateSelect`.

Some alternatives to get the desired filtering are:

```
Select[20 > #[[1]]["Day"] > 1 &] @ Data

(* or Select[20 > #["Day"] > 1 & @* First] @ Data *)
```

[image]

```
Cases[{_?(20 > #["Day"] > 1 &), _}] @ Data == %
```

> True

```
Select[#[[1]]["DayNameShort"] == "Wed" &] @ Data
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could transform your data into an `Association`:

```
time = Map[DateObject, DateRange[{2022, 1, 1}, {2022, 1, 31}]];
val = RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length @ time];

data = AssociationThread[time -> val];
```

Now you can use `Lookup` and `DateSelect` to get the values between two dates:

```
Lookup[data, DateSelect[time, Between[#Day, {3, 6}] &]]
```

{0.153392, 0.0392318, 0.127469, 0.526201}

If you also want to see the dates use `KeyTake`:

```
KeyTake[DateSelect[time, Between[#Day, {3, 6}] &]] @ data // Dataset
```

[image]

If you want to do this repeatedly, define your own little function to save some keystrokes:

```
ds[a_, b_] := DateSelect[a, Between[#Day, b] &]

Lookup[data, ds[time, {20, 21}]]
```

{0.94804, 0.0967288}